# No sku info found for record #1 to #7 when import csv file

Tags: magento, csv, import

I use Magmi (0.7.18) and Magento (1.8.1) to import 5 simple products and 1 configurable product but I get an error **No sku info found for record #1**, the same happens with other records. This is my config Datasources:

```
CSV import model: local
CSVs base directory: var/import
File to import: designerglass-new.csv
CSV separator: |
CSV Enclosure: " (double quote)
Checked Headerless CSV
```

I still fill fields in Configure Global Parameters, no any checked in General and Itemprocessors. This is my file is used to import: http://www.mediafire.com/download/jfssccjtaloh0yt/designerglass-new.csv. Can someone show me how to fix these errors?

Demo data:

```
sku,_store,attribute_set,type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,brands,category_ids,associated,categories,color,super_attribute_pricing,_config_attributes,config_attributes,cost,country_of_manufacture,country_orgin,custom_design,description,dimension,ebizmarts_mark_visited,frame_description,frame_styles,gallery,gender,gift_message_available,has_options,image,image_label,lenses,lenses_required,material,media_gallery,meta_description,meta_keyword,meta_title,minimal_price,model,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp_enabled,name,options_container,page_layout,prescription_sunglasses,price,required_options,short_description,size,small_image,small_image_label,special_price,status,tax_class_id,thumbnail,thumbnail_label,url_key,url_path,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_custom_option_store,_custom_option_type,_custom_option_title,_custom_option_is_required,_custom_option_price,_custom_option_sku,_custom_option_max_characters,_custom_option_sort_order,_custom_option_row_title,_custom_option_row_price,_custom_option_row_sku,_custom_option_row_sort,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr,,
Rayban RB5187 2000,admin,Designer Glass,simple,,,base,Ray-Ban,10,,10,SHINY BLACK,"size::48-45,color::SHINY BLACK",,,,,,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2000 from the Highstreet collection, available in SHINY BLACK with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,No,,Rectangle,,"Women, Men",,0,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,,,Acetate,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2000 from the Highstreet collection, available in SHINY BLACK with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings","Prescription RayBan, Wayfarer, Clubmaster, Rayban glasses, Rayban eyewear, Cheap Rayban, Ray Ban, mens Rayban, Womens Rayban, 2014",Rayban RB5150 2060,,egw4,Use config,Use config,Rayban RB5187 2000,Block after Info Column,,,87,0,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2000 from the Highstreet collection, available in SHINY BLACK with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",48-45,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,,Enabled,None,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,rayban-rb5187-2000,rayban-rb5187-2000.html,"Catalog, Search",567,9999,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,color,Black,,Full Rim,Highstreet
Rayban RB5187 2445,admin,Designer Glass,simple,,,base,Ray-Ban,10,,10,HAVANA/GREEN,"size::48-46,color::HAVANA/GREEN",,,,,,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2445 from the Highstreet collection, available in HAVANA/GREEN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,No,,Rectangle,,"Women, Men",,0,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,,,Acetate,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2445 from the Highstreet collection, available in HAVANA/GREEN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings","Prescription RayBan, Wayfarer, Clubmaster, Rayban glasses, Rayban eyewear, Cheap Rayban, Ray Ban, mens Rayban, Womens Rayban, 2014",Rayban RB5150 2061,,egw4,Use config,Use config,Rayban RB5187 2445,Block after Info Column,,,87,0,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2445 from the Highstreet collection, available in HAVANA/GREEN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",48-46,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,,Enabled,None,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,rayban-rb5187-2445,rayban-rb5187-2445.html,"Catalog, Search",567,9999,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,color,Havana,,Full Rim,Highstreet
Rayban RB5187 5076,admin,Designer Glass,simple,,,base,Ray-Ban,10,,10,TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE,"size::48-47,color::TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE",,,,,,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 5076 from the Highstreet collection, available in TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,No,,Rectangle,,"Women, Men",,0,/RB5187 5076.png,TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE,,,Acetate,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 5076 from the Highstreet collection, available in TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings","Prescription RayBan, Wayfarer, Clubmaster, Rayban glasses, Rayban eyewear, Cheap Rayban, Ray Ban, mens Rayban, Womens Rayban, 2014",Rayban RB5150 2062,,egw4,Use config,Use config,Rayban RB5187 5076,Block after Info Column,,,87,0,"The latest Rayban RB5187 5076 from the Highstreet collection, available in TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",48-47,/RB5187 5076.png,TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE,,Enabled,None,/RB5187 5076.png,TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE,rayban-rb5187-5076,rayban-rb5187-5076.html,"Catalog, Search",567,9999,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/RB5187 5076.png,TOP BROWN ON OPAL AZURE,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,color,Brown,,Full Rim,Highstreet
Rayban RB5187 5163,admin,Designer Glass,simple,,,base,Ray-Ban,10,,10,AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN,"size::48-48,color::AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN",,,,,,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 5163 from the Highstreet collection, available in AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,No,,Rectangle,,"Women, Men",,0,/RB5187 5163.png,AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN,,,Acetate,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 5163 from the Highstreet collection, available in AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings","Prescription RayBan, Wayfarer, Clubmaster, Rayban glasses, Rayban eyewear, Cheap Rayban, Ray Ban, mens Rayban, Womens Rayban, 2014",Rayban RB5150 2063,,egw4,Use config,Use config,Rayban RB5187 5163,Block after Info Column,,,87,0,"The latest Rayban RB5187 5163 from the Highstreet collection, available in AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",48-48,/RB5187 5163.png,AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN,,Enabled,None,/RB5187 5163.png,AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN,rayban-rb5187-5163,rayban-rb5187-5163.html,"Catalog, Search",567,9999,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/RB5187 5163.png,AZURE TRANSPARENT BROWN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,color,Brown,,Full Rim,Highstreet
Rayban RB5187 2445,admin,Designer Glass,simple,,,base,Ray-Ban,10,,10,HAVANA/GREEN,"size::48-50,color::HAVANA/GREEN",,,,,,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2445 from the Highstreet collection, available in HAVANA/GREEN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,No,,Rectangle,,"Women, Men",,0,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,,,Acetate,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2445 from the Highstreet collection, available in HAVANA/GREEN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings","Prescription RayBan, Wayfarer, Clubmaster, Rayban glasses, Rayban eyewear, Cheap Rayban, Ray Ban, mens Rayban, Womens Rayban, 2014",Rayban RB5150 2065,,egw4,Use config,Use config,Rayban RB5187 2445,Block after Info Column,,,87,0,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2445 from the Highstreet collection, available in HAVANA/GREEN with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",48-50,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,,Enabled,None,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,rayban-rb5187-2445,rayban-rb5187-2445.html,"Catalog, Search",567,9999,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/RB5187 2445.png,HAVANA/GREEN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,color,Havana,,Full Rim,Highstreet
Rayban RB5187,admin,Designer Glass,configurable,Designer Glasses,Root Catalog,base,Ray-Ban,10,"Rayban RB5187 2000,Rayban RB5187 2445,Rayban RB5187 5076,Rayban RB5187 5163,Rayban RB5187 2445",10,,,"size,color","size,color",,,,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2000 from the Highstreet collection, available in SHINY BLACK with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,No,,Rectangle,,"Women, Men",,1,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,,,Acetate,,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2000 from the Highstreet collection, available in SHINY BLACK with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings","Prescription RayBan, Wayfarer, Clubmaster, Rayban glasses, Rayban eyewear, Cheap Rayban, Ray Ban, mens Rayban, Womens Rayban, 2014",Rayban RB5150 2060,,egw4,Use config,Use config,Rayban RB5187,Block after Info Column,,,87,1,"The latest Rayban RB5187 2000 from the Highstreet collection, available in SHINY BLACK with free prescription lenses, inlcuding anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings",,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,,Enabled,None,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,rayban-rb5187,rayban-rb5187.html,"Catalog, Search",567,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/RB5187 2000.png,SHINY BLACK,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Rayban RB5187 2000,color,Black,,Full Rim,Highstreet
```

Comment: You should post part of your csv here, though it sounds like MTM probably has it right

Comment: I added data demo :) Please see my comment under MTM comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Your csv separator used in the csv file is `,` not the pipe `|`.

Comment: I used pipe symbol and ok. I checked Column mapper v0.0.3 and added some info and it worked but when I saw in database, the result I wanted is wrong. Some fields is empty and sku field includes all of them (table catalog_product_entity). I don't know what happen :(

Comment: If all of it went into `sku` it sounds like you haven't changed the config to use `,` as the separator